# AWS IAM. How to lookup my permissions/policy of my current role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As a user authenticated through SAML, I want to see all permissions I have on resources, such as do I have permission to run RDS queries, do I have permission to view billing reports.

I also want to compare my role's permissions to my co-worker's because he can do certain things but I can't, so I can figure out what additional permission needed to be added to my role.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general you can't, unless you were also granted a certain level of IAM permissions (to list and describe resources, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assume a role and then use the credentials to create the client to get the information.

[assume-role](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html#assume-role)

[ListPolicies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListPolicies.html)

```py
import boto3
iam = boto3.client('iam')
result =  iam.list_policies(OnlyAttached=True)
result['Policies']
```

[list-attached-role-policies](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html#list-attached-role-policies)

```
$ aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name myrolename
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "AdministratorAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
        }
    ]
}
```